# Fake URLs created automaticly

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

While checking my indexed pages in Google and Bing. i have found below links in search engine index listing. i am getting 404 errors in google webmaster tools. i got wordpress installed only. I dont have any plugin or any other CMS (Joomla) which may create those links.
how should i remove extra strings/values? what will be the code for .htaccess

Please ignore 2 spaces between url and strings/values.

deemasfashion.com/page/5/  **?Itemid=fnexvhxovxlxhzjb**

deemasfashion.com/page/2/  **?start=117**

deemasfashion.com/page/44/  **?wpmp_switcher=mobile**

deemasfashion.com/page/56/  **?attachment_id=fqtldnsdj**

deemasfashion.com/page/56/  **?attachment_id=pffbvrpggpx**

deemasfashion.com/page/13/  **?attachment_id=riohhjoahp**

deemasfashion.com/page/51/  **?start=108**

deemasfashion.com/  **?iapolo_com**

deemasfashion.com/  **?Itemid=nkuilfzcxvvb**

deemasfashion.com/  **?wpmp_switcher=desktop**

deemasfashion.com/page/38/  **wpmp_switcher**

deemasfashion.com/page/7/  **?wpmp_switcher=desktop=mobile**

deemasfashion.com/page/7/  **?wpmp_switcher=desktop**

deemasfashion.com/page/39/  **?2fou_com**

deemasfashion.com/page/22/  **?file**

deemasfashion.com/page/56/  **?option=com_content&view=article&id=94&Itemid=2**

deemasfashion.com/page/36/  **?option=com_content&view=article&id=62&Itemid=2**

deemasfashion.com/page/21/  **?iframe=true&width=90%25&height=90%25**

deemasfashion.com/  **?option=com_content&view=category&id=34%3Alatest-tech-news&Itemid=60**

deemasfashion.com/latest-pakistani-anarkali-pishwas-frock-wear/indian-style-light-golden-anarkali-fashion/  **function.session-start**

deemasfashion.com/latest-pakistani-anarkali-pishwas-frock-wear/latest-pakistani-outfit-mehndi-green-pishwas-churidar/  **function.require**

deemasfashion.com/latest-pakistani-bridal-wear/red-front-open-gown-off-white-bridal-wear-lehnga/  **function.include**

**i have used below .htaccess code but it is not working.**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(page/[0-9]+/).+$ /$1? [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.deemasfashion\.com$
RewriteRule ^deemasfashion\.com/?(.*)$ http://deemasfashion.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Majority of your bad URLs can be permanently redirected to correct one with this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+$
RewriteRule ^(page/[0-9]+/).*$ /$1? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Can you post this code by editing your question. It is impossible to read it from comments.

Comment: How are you testing it?

Comment: i have added this in htaccess file and then tested the fake urls

Comment: Did you test by trying to load URL in browser or some other testing method.

Comment: yes i have tried different fake URLs in browser. but they dont redirect and i have tried in GWT "fetch as google" it is still giving error 404

Comment: Is this code placed in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`? Try testing in a new browser to avoid 301 caching issues.

Comment: .htaccess is placed in document_root which is public_html in my case. and i have testing it in different browsers.

Comment: wordpress is not giving 404 actually but showing the page with extra string page/56/?option=com_content&view=article&id=94&Itemid=2. i just dont want this extra string after page number. page number plugin has been used here for pagination

Comment: thanks again i have tried but i think there is some problem with my htaccess. here is my whole code in txt file deemasfashion.com/temp.txt

Comment: `# code by anubhava` block needs be just below `RewriteBase /` line.

Comment: thanks you very very much. 98% problem have been resolved. Should i resolve this question. just joomla style URL left  deemasfashion.com/page/56/?option=com_content&view=article&id=94&Itemid=2

Comment: This should take care of all `/page/number` URLs. Only `deemasfashion.com/?option=com_content&view=category&id=34%3Alatest-tech-news&Itemid=60` type of URLs remain

Comment: would you please answer this as well . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19648075/remove-or-redirect-wrong-indexed-urls-from-my-website

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava would you please answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19648075/remove-or-redirect-wrong-indexed-urls-from-my-website