# Spam and Old URLs Modification

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is with the reference of [Fake URLs created automaticly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563565/fake-urls-created-automaticly). which was solved by https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava
.
By mistake or spam too many URLs have been created like below but now i want to redirect them to their respective post page URL.

I would prefer .htaccess. Please help

```
abc.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=4051&action=edit 
**Redirect to** 
abc.com/?p=4051
```

and

```
abc.com/page/56/?option=com_content&view=article&id=94&Itemid=2
**Redirect to** 
abc.com/page/56/
```

and

```
abc.com/category5/post-about-fashion/function.include
**Redirect to** 
abc.com/category5/post-about-fashion/
```

i am using wordpress. my permalink is /%category%/%postname%/. my htaccess code is below...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# code by anubhava
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+$
RewriteRule ^(page/[0-9]+/).*$ /$1? [L,NC,R=301]
# code by anubhava

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.deemasfashion\.com$
RewriteRule ^deemasfashion\.com/?(.*)$ http://deemasfashion.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://deemasfashion.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.htm$ http://deemasfashion.com/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need 2 additional rules:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+$
RewriteRule ^(page/[0-9]+/?).*$ /$1? [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(category[0-9]+/[^/]+/?).+$ /$1? [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)post=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/post\.php$ /?p=%1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Make sure these are top 3 rules just below `RewriteEngine On`

Comment: only one thing left which is my mistake. my categories are like "latest-pakistani-anarkali-pishwas-frock-wear" not "category5".

Comment: should i use your given code or is there any way to pick my each category

Comment: RewriteRule ^(latest-pakistani-anarkali-pishwas-frock-wear+/[^/]+/?).+$ /$1? [L,NC,R=301]

Comment: Yes writing a rule for each category like `RewriteRule ^(latest-pakistani-anarkali-pishwas-frock-wear/[^/]+/?).+$ /$1? [L,NC,R=301]` will definitely work. Unfortunately we cannot write a very smart single rule for matching these categories since these names vary.

Comment: wow, i am new to stackoverflow.com and it worked really very well for me. i have been searching for this 3 week and @anubhava have solved it in just few minutes.

Comment: is there any way i can send "4 bronze badges" to you. for solving my questions as apreciation. :)
thanks