# Remove or redirect wrong indexed urls from my website?

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is with the relation of my other questions [Spam and Old URLs Modification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568801/spam-and-old-urls-modification) and [Fake URLs created automaticly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563565/fake-urls-created-automaticly). **Would any body tell me that why they are being created?** and I want to redirect below urls. i want to remove extra string or spam from my domain name. i would prefer .htaccess. I am using wordpress.

```
deemasfashion.com/ **cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi**
deemasfashion.com/ page/38/wpmp_switcher
deemasfashion.com/ ?2fou_com
deemasfashion.com/ **?iapolo_com**
deemasfashion.com/ ?dur=2016 
deemasfashion.com/ **?dur=375**
deemasfashion.com/ ?file
deemasfashion.com/ ?option=com_content&view=frontpage&itemid=1
deemasfashion.com/ ?option=com_content&view=category&id=34:latest-tech- news&itemid=60
deemasfashion.com/ ?www.web3389.com
deemasfashion.com/ ?wpmp_switcher=desktop
deemasfashion.com/ ?option=com_content&view=category&id=34%3Alatest-tech-news&Itemid=60
```

**My .htaccess code in Document_root code is as follows.**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# code by anubhava
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+$
RewriteRule ^(page/[0-9]+/?).*$ /$1? [L,NC,R=301]

# Remove Edit Post
# RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)post=([^&]+) [NC]
# RewriteRule ^wp-admin/post\.php$ /?p=%1 [L,NC,R=301]

# function.session-start not working
# RewriteRule ^(latest-pakistani-anarkali-pishwas-frock-wear/[^/]+/?).+$ /$1? [L,NC,R=301]
# code by anubhava

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.deemasfashion\.com$

RewriteRule ^deemasfashion\.com/?(.*)$ http://deemasfashion.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://deemasfashion.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.htm$ http://deemasfashion.com/ [R=301,L]
# END WordPress
</IfModule>
```

Comment: @anubhava would you please answer this as well? i have tried to modify given rules but they are really tough for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try couple of these rules and directives at **before any other rule**:

```
# forward 404 to home page
ErrorDocument 404 /

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(page/[0-9]+)/.+$ /$1? [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=.+$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[^=]+$
RewriteRule ^$ /? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Really genius of you Again. Thank you very much and happy Diwali @anubhava. Every thing has been solved but only one exception. deemasfashion.com/?p=368 is redirecting to main page as well. i have used this type of links many times. post id can be changed.

Comment: Thanks, A very Happy Diwali to you as well. I am on mobile at present, will suggest a way out for you as soon as get to my computer.

Comment: thanks i have combined your old and new code. now this is working with .com and .com/page/. and no need to add exception for p=368.

Comment: but why those URLs have been created and indexed by search engine

Comment: These URLs have been probably indexed by some outside website/utility OR may be your old URLs.

Comment: i remember i ve installed wordpress from start. **is there any chance of hacking or any bad attempt?**

Comment: No it doesn't look like hacking. Try to find IP addresses of these bad URLs to figure out who's doing this.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. i will definitely do the research